# Laravel model form does not load data from database

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

With using Laravel 5.6, I am creating a Web. I have the database table `policies`. I can able to add data to the table using validator and jQuery to save, edit and delete records.

But the problems is, when I click the edit button, the `name` field(textbox) does not populate the values from the database (See the image).

[image: Table records]

[image: Model doesn't fetch name field value]

**`PolicyController`**

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all() , [
        //  'branch_Id' => 'required|max:25|unique:branches,branchId',
        'name' => 'required|max:25',
        'description' => 'max:50']);

        if ($validator->passes())
        {
            $policy = Policy::find($request->policy_Id);
            $policy->name = $request->name;
            $policy->description = $request->description;
            $policy->save();
            return response()
                ->json($policy);
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()
            ->all() ]);
    }
```

**editPolicy.blade.php**

```
<div class="box-body">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Policy ID
                  </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edpid" placeholder="Enter Policy Id" disabled>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Name
                  </label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edname" placeholder="Enter Policy Name">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Description
                  </label>
                  <textarea id="eddescr" class="form-control"></textarea>
               </div>
            </div>
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
$(document).on("click", ".editpolicy", function()
    {
        //console.log($(this).data('contact2'));
        $('#edpid').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#editpolicyid').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#edname').val($(this).data('name'));
        $('#eddescr').val($(this).data('descr'));

        $('#policyeditmodel').modal('show');

    });

    $("#edpolicyupdate").click(function()
    {
        var data = new FormData();
        var id = $("#editpolicyid").val();
        data.append('old_Id', $("#editpolicyid").val());
        data.append('policy_Id', $("#edpid").val());
        data.append('name', $("#edname").val());
        data.append('description', $("#eddescr").val());
        data.append('_token', $("#tokenedit").val());
        console.log($("#editpolicyid").val());
        console.log($("#edpid").val());
        console.log($("#edname").val());
        console.log($("#eddescr").val());
        console.log($("#tokenedit").val());
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: "<?php  echo url('/editpolicydata') ?>",
            success: function(data)
            {
                //console.log(data);
                if (data.error)
                {
                    $('#newerroredit').text(data.error[0]);
                    $("#errmsgedit").show();
                    return false;
                }
                console.log(data);

                $("#errmsgedit").hide();                

                $('#brc' + id).replaceWith("<tr id='brc" + data.id + "'><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs editpolicy' data-descr=" + data.description + " data-name=" + data.name + " data-id=" + id + "><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>Edit</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs viewpolicy' data-descr=" + data.description + " data-name=" + data.name + " data-id=" + id + "><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>View</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delpolicy' data-id=" + id + "><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>Delete</button></td></tr>");
            },
            error: function(json)
            {
                console.log(json);                            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: What is the output in the console for edname?

Comment: Nothing in console

Comment: Nothing shows in console

Comment: Please help anyone